# How to set property in function during object construction?

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties, initialization

how can I set property `c` in the function `func` below?
Right now, the last log prints `undefined` instead of calculated value.

```js
function X(a, b) {
  let func = function() {
    console.log('I am here');
      this.c = a + b;
    }

  this.a = a;
    this.b = b;

  func();
}

let x = new X(5, 4);
console.log(x.a + ' + ' + x.b + ' = ' + x.c);
```

Comment: why you need to have a `func` function to initialize variable `a`

Comment: my case is different, but I wanted to make the code simple to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `this` in `that` (new variable) and use it like `that.c = some_assignment`

```js
function X(a, b) {
    let that = this;
    let func = function() {
        console.log('I am here');
        that.c = a + b;
    }

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;

    func();
}

let x = new X(5, 4);
console.log(x.a + ' + ' + x.b + ' = ' + x.c);
```

Comment: I like this solution. Not as elegant as using => function what zabusa proposed, but it works with older JS also.

Answer (score 1):

use `arrow` functions in `es6` so you can access the parent `this`otherwise you can use to make `this` as a global variable and you can access the parent this

```js
function X(a, b) {
  let func = () => {
    console.log('I am here');
      this.c = a + b;
    }

  this.a = a;
    this.b = b;

  func();
}

let x = new X(5, 4);
console.log(x.a + ' + ' + x.b + ' = ' + x.c);
```

Answer (score 1):

- That's happening because the context of `this` is not from function `X`.
- For cross-browser and backend technology compatibilities, you can bind the `this` context using the function `bind`

```
func.bind(this)();
```

```js
function X(a, b) {
  let func = function() {
    console.log('I am here');
    this.c = a + b;
  }

  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;

  func.bind(this)();
}

let x = new X(5, 4);
console.log(x.a + ' + ' + x.b + ' = ' + x.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the ref of this in some variable. Generally, me, self or that.

```js
function X(a, b) {
  let me = this;
  let func = function() {
    console.log('I am here');
      me.c = a + b;
    }

  this.a = a;
    this.b = b;

  func();
}

let x = new X(5, 4);
console.log(x.a + ' + ' + x.b + ' = ' + x.c);
```